# Why can I not get my jQuery leftScroll animation to work?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I am trying to animate a simple horizontal scroll using jQuery but it will not fire, why is that?

http://jsfiddle.net/langoon/b5ZTH/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#1">1</a>
<a href="#2">2</a>
<a href="#3">3</a>

<section>
    <a name="1">1</a>
    <a name="2">2</a>
    <a name="3">3</a>
<section>
```

**CSS**

```
section { 
    width: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    }
a[name] { 
    width: 100%; 
    display: inline-block; 
    white-space: normal; 
    }
a[name='1'] { 
    background-color: green;
    }
a[name='2'] { 
    background-color: yellow;
    }
a[name='3'] { 
    background-color: red;
    }
```

**​jQuery**

```
$('a[href]').click(function(){

    $('section').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $(this.hash).offset().left
    }, 1000);

});​
```

Comment: @MCSI does not work for me and I am using Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the jQuery code to :

```
$('a[href]').click(function(){

    var basePos = $("a[name]").offset().left/-1; // Get position of first a[name]
    var scrollPos = $("a[name='" + this.hash.replace('#','') + "']").offset().left;

    $('section').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: basePos + scrollPos 
    }, 'fast');

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
var w = [];
var wt = 0;

$('section a').each(function(i,v){
    (i == 0) ? wt = 0 : wt += $(this).width();
     w.push(wt);
});


$('a[href]').click(function(){
    var n = this.hash.replace('#','');
    var el = $.find("a[name='"+n+"']");
    console.log(w[n-1]);
    $('section').animate({
        scrollLeft: w[n-1]
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the right direction. However your code has limitations, for example it assumes "a[href]" and "a[name]" are named in ascending numbers. I solved this by referencing the position of the first "a[name]" relative to to the position of the scroll to "a[name]".